# Как расшарить интернет по ethernet из wi-fi в Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: сеть, настройка, wifi, маршрутизация, ubuntu

В интернете куча форумов на эту тему но ничего конкретного. Попытаюсь всё разложить по полочкам, надеюсь мне помогут.![alt text][1]    Wi-Fi -  inet addr:192.168.189.1  Bcast:192.168.189.255  Mask:255.255.255.0    eth0 (wi-fi) -  inet addr:192.168.189.39  Bcast:192.168.189.255  Mask:255.255.255.0    eth1 -  inet addr:192.168.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.0 шлюз:192.168.189.1    PC - inet addr:192.168.1.2  Mask:255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 Wi-Fi раздаёт динамические адреса и его нельзя настраивать. Интернет соответственно через него.Нашёл на английском [ман][2], но мне он не понятен. Ещё на русском нашёл простую и доходчивую [статью][3], но у меня не заработало. Нужно заметить, что сеть у меня всячески ограниченная, например ping во внешку не работает, но адрес определяет.**На ubuntu 13.10**    :~$ ifconfig -a    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:65:ec:00:ab:74                UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:06:e6:f7:aa:1d                inet addr:192.168.189.182  Bcast:192.168.189.255  Mask:255.255.255.0              inet6 addr: fe80::e206:e6ff:fef7:aa1d/64 Scope:Link              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)                inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1        :~$ route    Таблица маршутизации ядра протокола IP    Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface    default         gate.wifi.main. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1    192.168.189.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 eth1**PC - Ubuntu 12.04.4**    :~$ ifconfig -a    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:26:aa:c3:e4                UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:48:28:60:df                UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:d4:64:6f:79                UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1    Kernel IP routing table    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkSZA.jpg  [2]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing/  [3]: http://ru.d-ws.biz/articles/icsLinuxAndWindows.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротенько, то нужно сделать

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Если нужно поразвернутее - пожалуйста вывод *ifconfig -a* и *route* в студию.

Если есть желание покопать в эту сторону - читаем про НАТ, МАСКАРАДИНГ, и iptables в целом.

Comment: Почитай статейку http://www.helplinux.ru/wiki/kb:quick-nat-dhcp-dnsТам как раз твой вариант

Comment: погорячился я с принятием ответа, но всё равно +. Я обновил содержание. Подскажите пожалуйста поконкретнее.

Answer (score 1):

- echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
- iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 0/0 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE

где -s адресс или диапазон адрессов локальной сети, а -d, в нашем случае внешний мир и тут менять ничего не надо,для Вас -s такой на пример 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: первая команда не сработала, но содержимое /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward изначально было "1"Вторая тоже не помогла: sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: C IP арессами не понятно. Т.е их нет, кто куда что раздает и на каких интерфейсах?

Comment: я не знаю почему их там нет. в графическом интерфейсе есть. настройки указаны выше

Answer (score 1):

На ubuntu 13.10 нужно сделать:

1) Устанавливаем службу фаерволла:

aptitude -y install iptables-persistent

2) Включаем NAT:

iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.189.182

service iptables-persistent save

3) Назначаем интерфейсу eth0 IP адрес, приводим конфиг /etc/network/interfaces примерно к такому виду:

auto eth0

allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet static

```
address 192.168.0.1
```

4) Перезапускаем сетевую службу:

service networking stop && service networking start

5) Устанавливаем DHCP сервер:

aptitude -y install isc-dhcp-server

6) Приводим конфиг /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf примерно к такому виду:

ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name-servers здесь через запятую вписываем IP адреса вашего интернет провайдера;

default-lease-time 600;

max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;

log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.10;

option routers 192.168.0.1;

}

7) Выбираем интерфейс, на котором будет работать DHCP сервер, конфиг /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server приводим к такому виду:

INTERFACES="eth0"

8) Запускаем DHCP сервер:

service isc-dhcp-server start

9) Теперь переподключаем кабель, который идёт от этого компьютера к PC и интернет там появится автоматически.

Comment: *не получается. DHCP я правда не устанавливал, т.к. в этом нет необходимости. причём после подключения второго компа инет отрубается полностью

Comment: Значит выпрямляйте руки. А DHCP сервер нужен всегда!

Comment: если бы DHCP сервер был всегда нужен, то наверное он всегда бы и стоял. А выпрямлялка рук тоже пока не работает... но я над этим работаю :)Кстати у Вы пишете (назначить интерфейсу eth0 ip-адрес), а как-же динамическое получение адреса от wi-fi?

Comment: Ну оно и так будет работать.